# A word that is a little less than cold

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for an adjective that says "It's cold, but not *that* cold".  For example, lukewarm means (in my mind) "It's warm, but not *that* warm", and I'm looking for its cold counterpart.  Every synonym I find for cold describes an increased cold, not a decreased cold.

Is there any word like this?

Comment: Less intense than "cold" is "cool."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cool:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Cool)  (from TFD)

> - moderately cold: a cool day.

Comment: You beat me while I was typing -- +1.

Comment: Ah, this is is so simple, why did I miss it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*Cool*, already suggested is reasonable.  From [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cool#Adjective), it means “Having a slightly low temperature; mildly or pleasantly cold”.

*Chilly* may connote a little colder than cool.  From [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chilly#Adjective), it means “Cold enough to cause shivering; or suddenly feeling cold”.

The adjectives *brisk* and *crisp* typically are used when temperatures are cool to chilly.  From en.wiktionary, *[brisk](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brisk#Adjective)*  means “Stimulating or invigorating. [eg] *This morning was a brisk fall day...*” and *[crisp](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crisp#Adjective)* means “Of weather, air etc.: dry and cold”, but *crisp* is also used with sense “fresh, invigorating ” [[merriam-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crisp)].

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'nippy'(=Pleasantly cold and invigorating)